# how to fix type mismatch json exception while parsing a json url in Android?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to retrieve `Json` data using a `URL`.  My Json array is posted below. I am getting a type mismatch json exception. Can any one guide me step by step where I am going wrong? My error logs are posted below.

Secondly, please tell me whether json parsing using a url is same as json parsing using a php from a server database.

Url : `http://166.62.17.208/json_preferencess.aspx`

```
 "items": [
        {
            "id": "11",
            "Item_Id": "123",   
            "Item_Name": "Chicken Cream Soup",
            "Price": "8",
            "Currency": "AED",
            "Category": "Soup",
            "Description": "Creamy Chicken Soup with garnish & side helpings",
            "Unit": "2",
            "food_type": "Non",
            "Image_Large": "/images_large/chickensoup.jpg",
            "Image_Thumb": "/images_large/chickensoup.jpg",
            "Timestamp": "6/23/2014 9:49:43 PM",
            "Promotion": "",
            "Item_Name_arabic": "حساء الطماطم",
            "Item_Name_russian": "",
            "Currency_arabic": "درهم",
            "Currency_russian": "",
            "Description_arabic": "حساء الطماطم",
            "Description_russian": "",
            "Note": "",
            "Nutritional_info": "",
            "extrafield_1": "",
            "extrafield_2": "",
            "preferncess": [
                "No Salt",
                "Extra Sugar"
            ],
            "preferncess_ids": [
                "1",
                "2"
            ],
            "price": [
                "4",
                "5"
            ],
            "preferncess_arabic": [
                "لا الملح",
                "سكر اضافية"
            ]
        }
        ],
    "category_Timestamp": "6/24/2014 1:05:28 PM",
    "questions": [
        {
            "q_id": "1",
            "q_question": "How would you rate our Menu ?",
            "q_option1": "Excellent",
            "q_option2": "Very Good",
            "q_option3": "Good",
            "q_option4": "Bad",
            "q_option5": "Terrible",
            "Timestamp": "9/12/2013 3:31:55 PM",
            "q_status": "1"
        },
         ],
```

MainActivity.class

```
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                //items = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                Log.i("json node",""+jsonObj);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                           }
                            }
```

Error logs

```
    06-27 06:55:50.154: W/System.err(2192): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"questions":[{"q_id":"1","q_question":"How would you rate our Menu ?","q_status":"1","q_option5":"Terrible","q_option3":"Good","q_option4":"Bad","q_option2":"Very Good","q_option1":"Excellent","Timestamp":"9\/12\/2013 3:31:55 PM"},{"q_id":"2","q_question":"How would you rate our presentation, taste and quality of food ?","q_status":"1","q_option5":"Terrible","q_option3":"Good","q_option4":"Bad","q_option2":"Very Good","q_option1":"Excellent","Timestamp":"9\/12\/2013 3:31:55 PM"},{"q_id":"3","q_question":"How would you rate the friendliness our staff members ?","q_status":"1","q_option5":"Terrible","q_option3":"Good","q_option4":"Bad","q_option2":"Very Good","q_option1":"Excellent","Timestamp":"9\/12\/2013 3:31:55 PM"},{"q_id":"4","q_question":"How would you rate our staff's performance and service?","q_status":"1","q_option5":"Terrible","q_option3":"Good","q_option4":"Bad","q_option2":"Very Good","q_option1":"Excellent","Timestamp":"9\/12\/2013 3:31:55 PM"},{"q_id":"5","q_question":"How would you rate the value for money ?","q_status":"1","q_option5":"Terrible","q_option3":"Good","q_option4":"Bad","q_option2":"Very Good","q_option1":"Excellent","Timestamp":"9\/12\/2013 3:31:55 PM"}],"categories":[{"categoryArabicName":"سلطة خضراء","catid":"0","categoryShortName":"Salads","categoryName":"Salads"},{"categoryArabicName":"المزة","catid":"1","categoryShortName":"Mezzah","categoryName":"Mezzah"},{"categoryArabicName":"الطبق الرئيسي","catid":"2","categoryShortName":"Main-Course","categoryName":"Main Course"},{"categoryArabicName":"معكرونة","catid":"3","categoryShortName":"Pasta","categoryName":"Pasta"},{"categoryArabicName":"مثوبة","catid":"4","categoryShortName":"Deserts","categoryName":"Deserts"},{"categoryArabicName":"حساء","catid":"5","categoryShortName":"Soup","categoryName":"Soup"}],"question_Timestamp":"9\/12\/2013 3:31:55 PM","items":[{"Image_Large":"\/images_large\/chickensoup.jpg","Promotion":"","food_type":"Non","Item_Name":"Chicken Cream Soup","Unit":"2","id":"11","Nutritional_info":"","Description_arabic":"حساء الطماطم","Image_Thumb":"\/images_large\/chickensoup.jpg","preferncess":["No Salt","Extra Sugar"],"extrafield_1":"","extrafield_2":"","Currency":"AED","Description_russian":"","Description":"Creamy Chicken Soup with garnish & side helpings","preferncess_ids":["1","2"],"Item_Name_russian":"","Currency_russian":"","Note":"","Item_Id":"123","preferncess_arabic":["لا الملح","سكر اضافية"],"Timestamp":"6\/23\/2014 9:49:43 PM","Category":"Soup","price":["4","5"],"Currency_arabic":"درهم","Price":"8","Item_Name_arabic":"حساء الطماطم"},{"Image_Large":"\/images_large\/pasta.jpg","Promotion":"","food_type":"Non","Item_Name":"Pasta Napolitan","Unit":"20","id":"12","Nutritional_info":"","Description_arabic":"حساء الطماطم","Image_Thumb":"\/images_large\/pasta.jpg","preferncess":["No Salt"],"extrafield_1":"","extrafield_2":"","Currency":"AED","Description_russian":"","Description":"Pasta in Napolitan Sauce","preferncess_ids":["3"],"Item_Name_russian":"","Currency_russian":"","Note":"","Item_Id":"501","preferncess_arabic":["لا الملح"],"Timestamp":"6\/23\/2014 9:47:45 PM","Category":"Pasta","price":["5"],"Currency_arabic":"درهم","Price":"18","Item_Name_arabic":"حساء الطماطم"},{"Image_Large":"\/images_large\/caeser-salad.jpg","Promotion":"","food_type":"Non","Item_Name":"Caeser Salad","Unit":"20","id":"13","Nutritional_info":"","Description_arabic":"حساء الطماطم حساء الطماطم حساء الطماطم حساء الطماطمحساء الطماطم","Image_Thumb":"\/images_large\/caeser-salad.jpg","preferncess":["No Salt","Extra Pepper"],"extrafield_1":"","extrafield_2":"","Currency":"AED","Description_russian":"","Description":"A Caesar salad is a salad of romaine lettuce and croutons dressed with Parmesan cheese.","preferncess_ids":["4","8"],"Item_Name_russian":"","Currency_russian":"","Note":"","Item_Id":"1001","preferncess_arab


   W/System.err(2122):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
   W/System.err(2122):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
   W/System.err(2122):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
   W/System.err(2122):  at info.androidhive.jsonparsing.MainActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:118)
   W/System.err(2122):  at info.androidhive.jsonparsing.MainActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
   W/System.err(2122):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
   W/System.err(2122):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   W/System.err(2122):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
  W/System.err(2122):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  W/System.err(2122):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  W/System.err(2122):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your data comes from server in array form and you try to convert data into json object.

Now try below method:-

```
                JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                JSONObject obj = jsonObj.getJSONObject(0);

                items = jsonObj.getJSONArray("items");
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                }
```

I think you are not getting item array that's why you getting error.

Comment: @user3256145 dnt mind will show us whole json string?

Comment: do you want me to post the whole json string?@Golu

Comment: I have posted the url and the string.please check

Answer (score 0):

Try to check type like following before casting

```
if (c.get(key) instanceof String)
                     {
                        JSONObject Lawset = c.getString(key);                        
                     } else if (c.get(key) instanceof JSONObject)
                     {
                        JSONObject Lawset = c.getJSONObject(key);                        

                        //try to retrieve data from json object
                     }
                     else if (c.get(key) instanceof JSONArray)
                    {
                        JSONArray Lawset = c.getJSONArray(key);
                                    //iterate to get data
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
        String jsonStr = "{\"items\":[{\"id\":\"11\",\"Item_Id\":\"123\",\"Item_Name\":\"Chicken Cream Soup\",\"Price\":\"8\",\"Currency\":\"AED\",\"Category\":\"Soup\",\"Description\":\"Creamy Chicken Soup with garnish & side helpings\",\"Unit\":\"2\",\"food_type\":\"Non\",\"Image_Large\":\"/images_large/chickensoup.jpg\",\"Image_Thumb\":\"/images_large/chickensoup.jpg\",\"Timestamp\":\"6/23/2014 9:49:43 PM\",\"Promotion\":\"\",\"Item_Name_arabic\":\"حساء الطماطم\",\"Item_Name_russian\":\"\",\"Currency_arabic\":\"درهم\",\"Currency_russian\":\"\",\"Description_arabic\":\"حساء الطماطم\",\"Description_russian\":\"\",\"Note\":\"\",\"Nutritional_info\":\"\",\"extrafield_1\":\"\",\"extrafield_2\":\"\",\"preferncess\":[\"No Salt\",\"Extra Sugar\"],\"preferncess_ids\":[\"1\",\"2\"],\"price\":[\"4\",\"5\"],\"preferncess_arabic\":[\"لا الملح\",\"سكر اضافية\"]}],\"category_Timestamp\":\"6/24/2014 1:05:28 PM\",\"questions\":[{\"q_id\":\"1\",\"q_question\":\"How would you rate our Menu ?\",\"q_option1\":\"Excellent\",\"q_option2\":\"Very Good\",\"q_option3\":\"Good\",\"q_option4\":\"Bad\",\"q_option5\":\"Terrible\",\"Timestamp\":\"9/12/2013 3:31:55 PM\",\"q_status\":\"1\"}]}";
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray items = jsonObj.getJSONArray("items");
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Id :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Item Id :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Item_Id"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Item Name :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Item_Name"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Currency :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Currency"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Category :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Category"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Description :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Description"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Unit :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Unit"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Food Type :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("food_type"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Image Large :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Image_Large"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Image Thumb :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Image_Thumb"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Timestamp :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Timestamp"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Promotion :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Promotion"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Item Name Arabic :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Item_Name_arabic"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Item Name Russian :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Item_Name_russian"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Currency Arabic :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Currency_arabic"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Currency Russian :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Currency_russian"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Description Arabic :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Description_arabic"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Description Russian :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Description_russian"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Note :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Note"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Nutritional Info :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Nutritional_info"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Extrafield_1 :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("extrafield_1"));
                    System.out.println(i + 1 + " Extrafield_2 :" + items.getJSONObject(i).getString("extrafield_2"));

                    JSONArray preferncess = items.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("preferncess");

                    for (int j = 0; j < preferncess.length(); j++) {
                        System.out.println("Preferncess " + j + 1 + ":" + preferncess.getString(j));
                    }

                    JSONArray preferncess_ids = items.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("preferncess_ids");

                    for (int j = 0; j < preferncess_ids.length(); j++) {
                        System.out.println("Preferncess IDs " + j + 1 + ":" + preferncess_ids.getString(j));
                    }
                    JSONArray price = items.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("price");

                    for (int j = 0; j < price.length(); j++) {
                        System.out.println("Price" + j + 1 + ":" + price.getString(j));
                    }
                    JSONArray preferncess_arabic = items.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("preferncess_arabic");

                    for (int j = 0; j < preferncess_arabic.length(); j++) {
                        System.out.println("Preferncess Arabic" + j + 1 + ":" + preferncess_arabic.getString(j));
                    }


                    System.out.println("Category TimeStamp :" + jsonObj.getString("category_Timestamp"));

                    JSONArray questions = jsonObj.getJSONArray("questions");
                    for (int k = 0; k < questions.length(); k++) {
                        System.out.println(i + 1 + " Question Id :" + questions.getJSONObject(k).getString("q_id"));
                        System.out.println(i + 1 + " Question :" + questions.getJSONObject(k).getString("q_question"));
                        System.out.println(i + 1 + " Question Option 1 :" + questions.getJSONObject(k).getString("q_option1"));
                        System.out.println(i + 1 + " Question Option 2 :" + questions.getJSONObject(k).getString("q_option2"));
                        System.out.println(i + 1 + " Question Option 3 :" + questions.getJSONObject(k).getString("q_option3"));
                        System.out.println(i + 1 + " Question Option 4 :" + questions.getJSONObject(k).getString("q_option4"));
                        System.out.println(i + 1 + " Question Option 5 :" + questions.getJSONObject(k).getString("q_option5"));
                        System.out.println(i + 1 + " Question Timestamp :" + questions.getJSONObject(k).getString("Timestamp"));
                        System.out.println(i + 1 + " Question Status :" + questions.getJSONObject(k).getString("q_status"));
                    }
                }
            }catch (Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```